# Design a PCB using Kapton film

Tags: pcb, heat, conductive

I am a novice in electronics and wanted to design PCB , as a final year project i am planning to do something related to room heaters so i have decided to use Kapto/polymide material for that.

I am planning to build a PCB like mentioned in this link
[Kapton 12v (4" x 2")](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/retired/11867)
Can anyone guide me how to achieve this using a Kapton film like [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B006ZFQNT6)

Any suggestions regarding process or steps for this particular use case would be helpful

Comment: many shops can do kapton or flex circuit or FPC. what you show is insulating tape not for PCB conductors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't do that.

1. The kapton tape you linked to has adhesive on one side, which will interfere with whatever you try to do with it.
2. Kapton is available in much more suitable forms, for example [these](http://www.professionalplastics.com/KAPTONFILMPOLYIMIDE?prrfnbr=124795&child=147825&calc=calc29&utm_medium=shoppingengine&utm_source=googlebase&utm_campaign=googlebase&cvsfa=4160&cvsfe=2&cvsfhu=534b4150542e3030325832342e3030305832342e303030484e&gclid=CJTzsPvny88CFQ5Efgod2ewCGQ) 24 x 24 inch sheets.
3. Kapton is one of the most common materials used as a substrate for flexible printed circuits. You can simply call your favorite flexible circuit fabricator and have them make whatever circuit you want from your gerbers.
4. If you insist on making it yourself, you can buy [Kapton pre-clad with copper](http://www.dupont.com/products-and-services/electronic-electrical-materials/flexible-rigidflex-circuit-materials/brands/pyralux-flexible-circuit/sub-brands/pyralux-copper-clad-laminates.html). Most likely you can process this with the same photoresists and etchants used by hobbyists for rigid PCBs.
5. You probably want some kind of higher-resistance material you can pattern on the kapton to make your heater element. Unfortunately I don't know what your options are here, particularly for materials that can stand up to flexing.

Answer (score 2):

This is a good shop for FPC boards .
They all the design info you need.

This is what they use for car mirror defrost heaters but NOT room heaters. There we use Nichrome or Tungsten wire for cost reasons.

https://www.protoexpress.com/flex-pcb